# Simple step-by-step guide to Django multiple databases please

Tags: python, django, django-database

I've been through a few posts and the Django documentation but still can't get multiple databases to work. I'm new to Django and feel quite confused indeed.

In my project, one app should use an existing vo.sqlite3 with lots of data in it. I want to be able to handle this vo.sqlite3 in my vo app, separately from the default database db.sqlite3 (the one that handles users, etc).

Would you anyone be able to point me to a simple step-by-step way to get such setup to work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An example, in your settings, set up your databases

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite1'),
    },
    'client1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite2'),
    },
}
```

Then wharever you perform a query, you can select the database.

```
UserModel.objects.using(db).get(username=username)
```

`db` = you database name

You can view the full example [here](http://techydiary.com/how-to-handle-multiple-db-in-django/)

Comment: Thanks, I finally manage to make it work with your suggestion. something missing was doing a `manage.py syncdb --database=vo`. This actually loads vo.sqlite3 with authentication and other tables, and ignores the existing tables in the objects defined by `models.py`.  It registers a `vo_` table linked to the object in `models.py`,  but I actually wanted to access the existing tables, any suggestions?

Comment: In short, the question is: how to link the objects in `models.py` to existing tables in the database instead of having `manage.py syncdb --database=vo` creating a new table? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Not only levi's solution above worked, I even managed to make automated routing work, see my settings.py and routers.py.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'vodb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'vo.sqlite3',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['vo.routers.vo_Router',]

DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'vo': 'vodb'}
```

routers.py

```
from django.conf import settings

class vo_Router(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'vodb'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'vodb'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db_list = ('default', 'vodb')
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        return True

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'vodb':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'vo'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'vo':
            return False
        return None
```

The piece that was missing was the execution of `manage.py syncdb --database=vodb`.  However, this added a lot of unnecessary Django tables to the app database `vo.sqlite3`, and even created a new table for the object defined in my `models.py`.

In my case, I wanted just to link existing tables (with data) in `vo.sqlite3` to the objects in `models.py`.  Is there a way to do it Django? Thanks.